# Create pivot table from SQL query results

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to convert the results from my SCCM 2012 query about user device affinity to show multiple columns per computer name.
Example of query results :-

[image]

Desired results format :-

[image]

Is it possible to create the desired table as part of the query, or do I need to manipulate the results as a second step?  There are 130,000 lines in my original query output representing approx 90,000 machines.

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: I suspect similar questions may have been asked (and possibly answered) before. Have you tried searching?

Comment: If there are 90,000 machines, how many users are there?  If you pivot that it's going to be one damn huge result - what will you do with it?

Comment: There can be up to 10 users registered to each machine based on user device affinity rules.  However, approx 82,000 machines only have 1 user as the Primary device user.  The answer provided by Les below is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This is for SQL Server (since you haven't tagged the DB) but I guess this is OK since you mention SCCM.

There are heaps of examples of dynamic pivots on here if the final number of [UserX] columns is unknown.

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM (VALUES 
 ('PC001', 'a1\user1')
,('PC002', 'a1\user2')
,('PC002', 'a1\user3')
,('PC003', 'a1\user4')
,('PC003', 'a1\user5')
,('PC003', 'a1\user6')
,('PC004', 'a1\user7')
,('PC005', 'a1\user8')
) A([Computer Name], UserName);

SELECT *
 FROM
(SELECT 'User'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Computer Name] ORDER BY [Computer Name])) [User]
,*
FROM #Temp) Src
PIVOT
(MAX(Username) FOR [User] IN ([User1], [User2],[User3])
)Pvt


Computer Name User1    User2    User3
------------- -------- -------- --------
PC001         a1\user1 NULL     NULL
PC002         a1\user2 a1\user3 NULL
PC003         a1\user4 a1\user5 a1\user6
PC004         a1\user7 NULL     NULL
PC005         a1\user8 NULL     NULL

(5 row(s) affected)
```

Off the top of my head, yes, you can add this to your original query - put your query in place of my `#Temp` as in

```
SELECT *
   FROM
  (SELECT 'User'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Computer Name] ORDER BY [Computer Name])) [User]
,*
  FROM (Your query goes here) Blah
) Src
etc
```

) or just select your query into a temp table - just add `INTO #TempTableName` into your query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Les.  This is exactly what I was after.  Cheers :)